# Matchmaking in Animalia

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge, visual, animals

**These animals are wrongly paired:**

> (1) *Luscinia megarhynchos* & (2) *Oriolus traillii*

[image: Luscinia megarhynchos maximus]
[image: Oriolus traillii V.]

> (3) *Python regius* & (4) *Electrophorus electricus*

[image: Python regius biggus]
[image: Electrophorus electricus fluxus]

> (5) *Apis mellifera* (Q) & (6) *Lucanidae*

[image: Apis mellifera (Q)]
[image: Lucanidae canor]

> (7) *Larus crassirostris* & (8) *Pinctada*

[image: Larus crassirostris]
[image: Pinctada comprimo]

> (9) *Panthera leo* & (10) *Puma concolor coryi*

[image: Panthera leo capillus luxus]
[image: Puma concolor coryi]

**Rearrange them into the correct pair and explain your reasoning.**

---

Note:

> - Order of rows does not matter.
> - Additional tags that are vaguely relevant: [rebus](/questions/tagged/rebus), [wordplay](/questions/tagged/wordplay)

Hint:

> *Luscinia megarhynchos*' ability

Comment: Adding primary research on its common name: 1) Common nightingale 2) Maroon oriole 3) ball/royal python 4) Electric eel 5) (queen) honey bee 6) stag beetle 7) black-tailed gull 8) Pinctada (oyster) 9) lion 10) florida panther

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are

> references to songs.

(1) *Luscinia megarhynchos* 1978 (UK) - S (AS)

> [Maxine Nightingale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxine_Nightingale#Singles)'s 1978 UK single, A-side "**Lead Me On**".

(2) *Oriolus traillii* 2014 - T1

> [2014 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V_(Maroon_5_album)) by Maroon Five, track 1 is "**Maps**". (thanks @NudgeNudge)

(3) *Python regius* 1971 - S2, T2 (UK)

> [1971 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Another_Monty_Python_Record) by Monty Python, UK version, side 2, track 2 is "**Spam**".

(4) *Electrophorus electricus* 1985 - S1, T4

> [1985 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fly_on_the_Wall_(AC/DC_album)) by AC/DC, side 1, track 4 is "**Danger**" (thanks @NudgeNudge)

(5) *Apis mellifera* (Q) 2008 - D1, T2

> [2008 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am..._Sasha_Fierce) by Beyoncé (Queen B), disk 1, track 2 is "**Halo**". (thanks @NudgeNudge)

(6) *Lucanidae* 1966 - S (BS)

> 1966 single by The Beatles, B-side. There are [several options](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Beatles_discography#Singles), but the only one that fits the solution below is "**Rain**".

(7) *Larus crassirostris* 1982 - T3 (UK)

> [1982 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Flock_of_Seagulls_(album)) by A Flock of Seagulls, UK version, track 3 is "**I Ran (So Far Away)**"

(8) *Pinctada* 1991 - T9

> [1991 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ten_(Pearl_Jam_album)) by Pearl Jam, track 9 is "**Garden**" (thanks @NudgeNudge)

(9) *Panthera leo* 2009 (DEC) - T6

> [December 2009 album](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_State_vs._Radric_Davis) by Gucci Mane, track 6 is "**Lemonade**".

(10) *Puma concolor coryi* 2017 - S

> "**Hola**", 2017 single by Flo Rida (thanks @NudgeNudge)

So the pairings are

> Anagrams:
>  (1) "Lead Me On" & (9) "Lemonade"
>  (2) "Maps" & (3) "Spam"
>  (4) "Danger" & (8) "Garden"
>  (5) "Halo" & (10) "Hola"
>  (6) "Rain" & (7) "I Ran"

Comment: 2 is probably rot13(Znebba Svir - Zncf), which is rot13(Fcnz erirefrq). That's probably something to do with the pairing.

Comment: @NudgeNudge Yeah, also note rot13[Enva naq V Ena]...

Comment: Another: rot13(5 vf zbfg yvxryl Unyb ol Orlbapr (Dhrra Orr) juvyr 10 vf cebonoyl Ubyn ol Sybevqn)

Comment: And 9 could be rot13(Yrzbanqr ol Thppv Znar?). It fits. Sorry I'll stop now hahaha

Comment: @NudgeNudge Nice, you're on fire!

Comment: Seems like a bit of a stretch but they both fit their clue so here it goes: 4 is most likely rot13(Qnatre ol NPQP), and 8 is rot13(Tneqra ol Crney Wnz)

Comment: @NudgeNudge & jafe Impressive! Also, if you feel like identifying from the picture alone is too broad or stretchy. There's another element in the puzzle that would help narrow down or confirm your presumed stretchy answer.